# Integration of Logistic distribution in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration

The probability density function of Logistic distribution $f(x) = e^{-x} (1+e^{-x})^{-2}$

```
LL_cdf <- function(x) ((1+exp(-x))^(-1) # cumulative distribution function of logistic distribution

LL_pdf <- function(x) ( (exp(-x))*(1+exp(-x))^-2 ) # Probability density function (pdf) of logistic distribution
```

The integration of the pdf of any distribution on its support must be one. We integrate the pdf of **logistic distribution** on its support $x \in [-\infty,\infty]$ but It gives error message. We mention the the **error message in code below**. Why the pdf of the logistic distribution does not integrate over its support $x \in [-\infty,\infty]$ in **R**?

```
integrate( LL_pdf, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)$value 

Error in integrate(LL_pdf, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf) : 
  non-finite function value
```

Comment: `integrate( LL_pdf, lower = -Inf, upper = 0)` also fails.

Comment: I got 0.5, Actually it is useless because we need to integrate over the support of $X \in (\infty, \infty)$ @StephanKolassa

Comment: It's not totally useless as the PDF is symmetric around 0.

Comment: `integrate( LL_pdf, lower = -Inf, upper = 0)` gives you `0.5`? That is interesting, it suggests some strange difference. I am running R 4.0.2 on Windows 10. What does `sessionInfo()` tell you?

Comment: You are right. I am using R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24) @StephanKolassa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with your implementation of the density function as it produces ratios of the type `Inf/Inf = NaN` for large negative values

```
> LL_pdf(-1000)
[1] NaN
```

The implementation of a function should avoid this kind of numerical issues (`0/0`, `Inf/Inf`).

A solution is to implement the log density, which is numerically stable, and to return the exponential of the log density, which avoids this kind of issues:

```
LL_pdf2 <- Vectorize(function(x){
  log.val <- -x -2*log(1+exp(-x))
  return(exp(log.val))
  })  # Probability density function (pdf) of logistic distribution
```

Then, you obtain,

```
> LL_pdf2(-1000)
[1] 0
> 
> integrate( LL_pdf2, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)$value
[1] 1
```

You can compare these results with those obtained with `dlogis`

```
> dlogis(-1000)
[1] 0
> integrate( dlogis, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)$value
[1] 1
```